# Dynamically Reference an Object Property Using a String

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to reference a public property from a string. How can this be done in vb.net?
I have the text value of "FirstName" stored in strucParam(i).TxtPropertyName.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
Dim tmpValue As String
Dim ucAppName As UserControl_appName = CType(Parent.FindControl(strucParam(i).ParentFindControl), UserControl_appName)

tmpValue = ucAppName.FirstName.Text
```

How can I use the value in strucParam(i).TxtPropertyName so that I can remove ".FirstName" from my code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c), but I'll answer it for you since you're a VB user and probably didn't consider C# in your searches.

Suppose you have an object of any type stored in a variable called `objObject`, and the name of the property stored in a variable called `strPropertyName`. You do the following:

```
tmpValue = objObject.GetType().GetProperty(strPropertyName).GetValue(objObject, Nothing)
```

As a final note: please, *please* consider dropping pseudo-Hungarian notation. It's of no value when working with a statically typed language like VB.NET.

**Edit:**

> The FirstName property is in reality a text box. So don't I need to somehow reference .Text in the code?
>   `tmpFirstName = ucAppName.GetType().GetProperty(strucParam(i).PropertyName).GetValue(objAppNav, Nothing)`

Try this:

```
Dim textBox as TextBox
Dim tmpValue as String

textBox = CType(ucAppName.GetType().GetProperty(strucParam(1).PropertyName).GetValue(objAppNav, Nothing), TextBox)
tmpValue = textBox.Text
```

Basically, you have to cast the value of the property to a TextBox type, then grab the Text property from it.

Comment: I was unable to use null. I had to substitute it with Nothing.  When running the following code, I get an "Object does not match target type" error. The FirstName property is in reality a text box. So don't I need to somehow reference .Text in the code?   tmpFirstName = ucAppName.GetType().GetProperty(strucParam(i).PropertyName).GetValue(objAppNav, Nothing)

Comment: @crjunk: my bad, I'm a C# guy and forgot to translate. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! In honor of your help, I will no longer use pseudo-Hungarian notation. :)  I had a typo in the code I posted here. My final solution was:                     Dim textBox As TextBox
                    textBox = CType(ucAppName.GetType().GetProperty(strucParam(i).PropertyName).GetValue(ucAppName, Nothing), TextBox)